# Why did the Australian bushfires cause pitch darkness during the daytime?

Tags: wildfire, fire

Saturday 4th January was truly an extroadinary and terrible day for the south-east corner of Australia. Skies turned pitch black at around 3-5 pm, when normally these areas would be in daylight. I have never been aware of this sort of phenomenon. Is it possible that thick smoke alone could have caused this, or was it larger particles such as burnt leaves and bark, picked up by strong updraughts from pyrocumulus clouds? It is worth noting that this occurred right before a cold front passed through the area, bringing southerly winds, and that pyrocumulus clouds had formed, and lightning was being generated from them.

Comment: Welcome :-) I just recently learned about pyrocumulus clouds. Yeah, it is probably dark beneath them. Random image: https://thumbs.gfycat.com/WelldocumentedSelfassuredHookersealion-mobile.jpg

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible for smoke to cause this, though I can only cite first-hand experience as evidence.

Comment: I'm close to the fires (but not directly impacted). Our skies have been either grey, orange grey, or (on the worst days) deep dark red, with a constant smell of smoke and ash blanketing everything. It's not unsurprising to me that as you get closer to the source of all this the sky would darken even worse than what I've seen.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question ("What causes it?"), but historically, you may be interested in [New England's Dark Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_England%27s_Dark_Day), when what is presumed to be a Canadian forest fire in 1780 caused New England's (a USA state south of Canada) sky to turn so dark, candles were needed around noon-time. That occurrence is speculated to be a combination of smoke from the forest fire drifting south, in addition to cloud cover and fog.

Comment: @Jamin Grey: New England is actually a region, composed of six US states: Vermont, New Hampshire, Maine, Massachusetts, Connecticut, and Rhode Island.

Comment: @jamesqf I'm an USA-born American who've lived my whole in the USA. I'mma go hides my face in shame for just now learning what you explained. =P

Comment: @JaminGrey Obligatory xkcd: [you're one of today's lucky 10.000](https://www.xkcd.com/1053/) (and I'm one of -a bit more of- them too, even if I'm not American ;) )

Comment: @Jamin Grey: Don't feel too bad.  I'm often confused when people use those stupid two letter state codes, one of which is NE, and my first thought is that they're in New England :-)  And then there's postal CA = California vs internet CA = Canada...

Answer (score 12):

It's a combination of both the density and amount of smoke in the air and [ash](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2020/jan/04/australia-bushfires-week-of-anger-scott-morrison) produced by the fire.

The thing about [cold fronts and bush fires](https://mobile.abc.net.au/news/2019-11-11/fire-weather-and-why-tuesday-looks-so-bad/11693894?pfmredir=sm) is they make the conditions for fire worse by pushing hot air in front of them. They have been blamed for the severity of the bush fires in Victoria in 2009, 1983 and 1939.

Answer (score 2):

It was a combination of thick smoke and pyrocumulus clouds. Possibly there might have been other types of cloud as well, Ash rising on the updraught may also have been a factor. I am informed that normal types of cloud sometimes made an appearance during the drought. Near-pitch darkness in daylight hours is also characteristic of volcanic eruptions, but I am not suggesting that volcanic eruptions were a factor in this case, though they make an analogy.

During cumulonimbus events in England, usually accompanied by rain and thunder, we often get very dim light in mid afternoon, long before evening time, though I wouldn't describe it as pitch darkness but more a sort of twilight. If enormous plumes of smoke were added, it very likely would have become almost pitch dark.

Comment: A standard CB is not a pyrocumulus and Australia is not England (i mean geographically ;-)) And the rules demand that answers be underlain with proof.

Comment: Not England? Well blow me down, I thought it was one of the southern counties!

Comment: UK: I remember when the smoke from the Buncefield oil depot explosion/fire drifted overhead, thousands of feet up. It still looked sunny, but it was far too dark.

Answer (score 1):

If you think how white smoke looks when it is rising elsewhere and you are looking at sunlight reflecting off it ... what you are then seeing, is some of the  light that the folks who have that smoke between them and the sun are not getting. Smoke will also absorb a lot of sunlight (and re-radiate it as infra-red), especially if it's sooty black smoke rather than whitish ash.

On a gloomy note, you are experiencing what a nuclear war would cause on a global scale (a nuclear winter, caused by the ashes of civilisation). At least your smoke is not radioactive and relatively short-term ....